# Using -mfloat-abi=hard in eclipse

Tags: c++, c, cross-compiling

I am trying to cross compile in eclipse using the arm gcc compiler. I go to projrct , properties and set the c/c++ compile option and set the flag to  -mfloat-abi=hard.
It throws the following exception while building:

```
**** Build of configuration Debug for project HelloWorld ****

make all 
Building file: ../src/HelloWorld.c
Invoking: GCC C Compiler
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -I/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include -O0 -g3 -Wall -mfloat-abi=hard -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/HelloWorld.d" -MT"src/HelloWorld.d" -o "src/HelloWorld.o" "../src/HelloWorld.c"
Finished building: ../src/HelloWorld.c

Building target: HelloWorld
Invoking: GCC C Linker
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -L/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/lib -mfloat-abi=hard -o "HelloWorld"  ./src/HelloWorld.o   
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: error: ./src/HelloWorld.o uses VFP register arguments, HelloWorld does not
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: failed to merge target specific data of file ./src/HelloWorld.o
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [HelloWorld] Error 1

**** Build Finished ****
```

It builds fine without that flag. But I need to set it for it to run on the beaglebone.Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Output after using  -print-multi-lib

```
**** Build of configuration Debug for project HelloWorld ****

make all 
Building file: ../src/HelloWorld.c
Invoking: GCC C Compiler
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -I/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include -O0 -g3 -Wall -mfloat-abi=hard -c -fmessage-length=0  -print-multi-lib -MMD -MP -MF"src/HelloWorld.d" -MT"src/HelloWorld.d" -o "src/HelloWorld.o" "../src/HelloWorld.c"
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc: error: ./src/HelloWorld.o: No such file or directory
.;
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
make: *** [HelloWorld] Error 4
.;@mfloat-abi=softfp
hf;@mfloat-abi=hard
Finished building: ../src/HelloWorld.c

Building target: HelloWorld
Invoking: GCC C Linker
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -L/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/lib -mfloat-abi=hard -o "HelloWorld"  ./src/HelloWorld.o   

**** Build Finished ****
```

Comment: Please show the compilation line for `./src/HelloWorld.o`

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9753749/arm-compilation-error-vpf-registered-used-by-executable-not-object-file

Comment: Edited the question. Please take a look at it.