# FreeRTOS with C++ main file

Tags: c++, freertos

I am trying to use C++ application with FreeRTOS.
I come to know about this post :- https://sourceforge.net/p/freertos/discussion/382005/thread/5d5201c0 but I am not sure how and where to add this TaskCPP.h file.

Right now I have very simple main.cpp file something like this.

```
int main(void)
{
//Set priority bits to preempt priority
NVIC_PriorityGroupConfig(NVIC_PriorityGroup_4);
for( ;; );
return 0;
}
```

And this gives me an error :-

```
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.4/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: error: STM32F4_FreeRTOS.axf uses VFP register arguments, /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.4/libgcc.a(unwind-arm.o) does not

/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.4/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: failed to merge target specific data of file /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.4/libgcc.a(unwind-arm.o)
```

I am not sure what is wrong with settings.

Comment: Usually you should start the scheduler in the main function (an operation that never returns).

Comment: Yes, I want to start Scheduler in main function but I am getting error after using NVIC_PriorityGroupConfig(NVIC_PriorityGroup_4); function in main. If I am able to solve this error then I can go further and add Scheduler and TaskCreate functions.

Comment: Are you trying to link against a library (or object file), that wasn't compiled for this target?

Comment: If I comment out NVIC_PriorityGroupConfig(NVIC_PriorityGroup_4); function. Code compiles fine. So I think I am missing something which required if I want to use C functions in C++ file? 

Yes I am using -mfloat-abi=hard so I have added Library :-
LIBS = /usr/arm-none-eabi/lib/armv7e-m/fpu/libc_s.a /usr/arm-none-eabi/lib/armv7e-m/fpu/libm.a

Answer (score 1):

That error is related to your tool chain. Your target triple indicates, a more generic tool chain, but FreeRTOS seems to use more specific ARM features. You may want to read this question: [ARM compilation error, VFP registered used by executable, not object file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9753749/arm-compilation-error-vpf-registered-used-by-executable-not-object-file)

As workaround: call your compiler with `-print-multi-lib` and check whether the libraries required by FreeRTOS are available. If they are, you'll have to enable them. If they are not, you'll have to use another tool chain.