# How to interpret the output of gcc -print-multi-lib

Tags: gcc, output, cross-compiling

`man gcc` explains that `-print-multi-lib` lists switches and how they're separated, but not what e.g.

```
.;
```

or

```
.;
32;@m32
x32;@mx32
```

could mean. I can't even tell if I have `multilib` support as requested by https://stackoverflow.com/a/9753955/1797006.

I'm using `gcc` 5.3.1 and 4.6.3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The output in form: `.;` without any additional lines means that no multilibs were found on your host.

In general:

> `-print-multi-lib`: This debugging option causes GCC to display the mapping from multilib directory names to compiler switches that enable
>   them. This information is extracted from the specification files used
>   by the compiler, in which the directory name is separated from the
>   switches by a semicolon, and each switch starts with an @ symbol
>   instead of the traditional dash/minus symbol, with no spaces between
>   multiple switches.

**Source**: *The Definitive Guide to GCC* by William von Hagen  [2nd edition, Apress 2006]. Please notice - this book covers GCC 4.x.y versions but I haven't found any information about some radical changes in this scope in GCC > 5.

Therefore, the second output in your post shows information about two multilibs.

Usage of multilib is typical for cross-compilation purpose.

I think that another 
quote for the same book is worth mentioning about another useful switch:

> `-print-multi-directory`: This debugging option causes GCC to print the directory name corresponding to the multilib selected by any other
>   switches that are given on the command line. This directory is
>   supposed to exist in the directory defined by the GCC_EXEC_PREFIX
>   environment variable.