# Cross-compilation for ARM-embedded

Tags: ubuntu, arm, embedded, crypto++

I am trying to install Crypto++ for cross-compilation on a beaglebone black and I am using Ubuntu for compilation. I am quite a newbie in this please help me out.

I did:

```
. ./setenv-embedded.sh
```

And everything seems fine. Then I tried to the the make command:

```
make -f GNUmakefile-cross static static dynamic cryptest.exe
```

But I did not get the same output as shown at [ARM Embedded (Command Line)](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/ARM_Embedded_%28Command_Line%29).

And then trying to test it.

```
/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-readelf -h ./cryptest.exe | grep -i 'class\|machine' 
Class:       Elf32
Machine:     Intel 80386
```

The machine is still Intel not ARM:

[image]

Can you help me with this one?

Thank you very much

Comment: Don't post images. Paste the text in your question!

Comment: @Lester - I was able to compile Crypto++ natively on a BeagleBone Black (no need for cross-compiling). The BBB image is preloaded with Git, GCC, Make, etc. The Debian images include Qt. Have you tried SSH'ing into you BBB and compiling just like you would on a desktop?

Comment: @Lester - we recently added a message to [direct you to the next step after running `setenv-*.sh`](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/commit/a6090c64edfc51d9d573398d4b266b2718d09546). I'm kicking myself in in my ass-end because I should have realized it was needed a long time ago.

Comment: really appreciate this @jww Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you notice, you get a message "nothing needs to be done for 'static'" (and friends).

You need to perform a `make clean` or `make distclean` to remove the previous i686/x86_64 build.

You should also ensure you are using the latest `GNUmakefile-cross` and the latest `setenv-embedded.sh`. *If* you are using Crypto++ 5.6.3 or above, then its already in Git and you only need to `git pull`. *If* you are using Crypto++ 5.6.2 and earlier, then you can download them from [ARM Embedded (Command Line)](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/ARM_Embedded_%28Command_Line%29).

---

Here's what it looks like for me on Ubuntu 14.04.

```
$ . ./setenv-embedded.sh 
CPP: /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-cpp
CXX: /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-g++
AR: /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-ar
LD: /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-ld
RANLIB: /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc-ranlib-4.7
ARM_EMBEDDED_TOOLCHAIN: /usr/bin
ARM_EMBEDDED_CXX_HEADERS: /usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.7.3
ARM_EMBEDDED_FLAGS: -I/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.7.3 -I/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.7.3/arm-linux-gnueabi
ARM_EMBEDDED_SYSROOT: /usr/arm-linux-gnueabi

$ make -f GNUmakefile-cross 
/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ -DNDEBUG -g2 -Os -fPIC -pipe
  -I/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.7.3
  -I/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.7.3/arm-linux-gnueabi
  --sysroot=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi -c cryptlib.cpp
  ...
```

And then:

```
$ /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-readelf -h ./libcryptopp.a | grep -i 'class\|machine' | head -2
  Class:                             ELF32
  Machine:                           ARM
```

---

> But I did not get the same output as shown at ARM Embedded (Command Line).

I can't dump things for `libcryptopp.so` or `cryptest.exe` because it appears Ubuntu tool chain took a regression. The linker can no longer link an executable.

---

Ubuntu's cross-compiler is kind of borked. We filed a few bug reports against in when writing the examples on the wiki. Its the reason we provide an example of using ARM's cross-compiler at [ARM Embedded (Bare Metal)](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/ARM_Embedded_%28Bare_Metal%29).

Comment: Your solution works. Thanks alot. However I am having this trouble.

"/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: failed to merge target specific data of file zinflate.o"

do you know what this is ?

Comment: @Lester - I have not encountered it, so I don't know how to fix it. You might take a look at [ARM compilation error, VPF registered used by executable, not object file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9753749).