# Compiling ARM executable with static library, VFP register arguments error despite same compiler flags

Tags: c, arm, static-libraries

I am developing a static library for a client, to be used on a Cortex M4F processor. As a test platform, I am using a [Texas Instruments Tiva C series board](https://www.ti.com/tool/EK-TM4C1294XL). When trying to link an executable against this library, I am getting the error `...project0.axf ...uses VFP register arguments, ../../libsleep.a(setters_getters.o) does not.` but none of the past solutions I have found are working.

- I read [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9753749/arm-compilation-error-vfp-registers-used-by-executable-not-object-file), which was helpful, but ultimately didn't solved my issue. It did inspire the next bullet point:
- I have copy-pasted the `gcc` flags for my library compiling step from the executable make file to make sure they are the same.
- I have verified that I am using the same ARM GNU Toolchain compiler (same executable), `arm-none-eabi-gcc`, when making the library and the executable. I am also using `arm-none-eabi-gcc-ar` from that toolchain to make the static library.

So far, I have confirmed that I can compile an executable for my laptop which links against my static library (compiled for my laptop, of course) just to check there's not some error in the library code.

I am now trying to modify TI's `project0` in their [TivaWare SDK](https://www.ti.com/tool/SW-TM4C) to simply call some functions from this library as part of the loop that blink the lights. Before modifying this, I confirmed that I can `make` this executable (as TI ships it) and flash it to the Tiva board. Once I add the function calls and modify the Makefile to add the `.a`, it no longer builds. (Check the end of this post for the error messages I get from `make`.

Past questions pointed me towards the importance of setting `-mfloat-abi=` the same when compiling the library and the executable. Looking at the TivaWare `makedefs` file, which ultimately configures these flags, I copy and pasted them into the script I use to build the library. FWIW, both steps are using `-mfloat-abi=hard`.

Just to sanity check myself, I also tried compiling the library with `-mfloat-abi=soft` and `=softp` just to verify I wasn't confused about the error and getting it backwards.

Here are the two steps I ultimately use to build my library; the gcc args after the `-I`s are copy-pasted out of TI's makefile, trying to make sure those are exactly the same.

```bash
STATIC_LIB_NAME="libsleep.a"

for file in $(ls src/lib/*.c)
do
  # replace .../some_file.c with .../some_file.o
  out_file="$OBJECT_DEST"/"$(echo "$file" | cut -d '.' -f 1 | cut -d '/' -f 3).o"

  arm-none-eabi-gcc -Isrc/include/ -Isrc \
      -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb \
      -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard \
      -Dgcc \
      -Os \
      -ffunction-sections \
      -fdata-sections \
      -MD \
      -std=c99 \
      -Wall \
      -pedantic \
      -DPART_${PART} \
      -DTARGET_IS_TM4C129_RA1 \
      -c $file -o $out_file
done

arm-none-eabi-gcc-ar rcs "$STATIC_LIB_DEST"/"$STATIC_LIB_NAME" "$OBJECT_DEST"/*.o
```

For copyright reasons, I cannot share TI's makefile, but the only line I modified was adding a step to the build rule for the `.axf` file on `project0`:

```
${COMPILER}/project0.axf: ${STATIC_LIB_DIR}/libsleep.a
```

Running `make` in that directory gives me an error like the following for each `.o` file in `libsleep.a`. **update:** Here, `setters_getters.c` is one of the source files compiled into `setters_getters.o` in the bash `for` loop above with `-mfloat-abi=hard`.

```
arm-none-eabi-ld: error: gcc/project0.axf uses VFP register arguments, ../../output/static/libsleep.a(setters_getters.o) does not
arm-none-eabi-ld: failed to merge target specific data of file ../../output/static/libsleep.a(setters_getters.o)
```

Just in case it's helpful, after the above error for each object file, I get a bunch of undefined reference errors, but I expect that's just related to the previous linking steps failing.

```
arm-none-eabi-ld: /path/to/arm-gnu-toolchain-12.2.mpacbti-rel1-darwin-arm64-arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/12.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard/libc.a(libc_a-sbrkr.o): in function `_sbrk_r':
sbrkr.c:(.text._sbrk_r+0xc): undefined reference to `_sbrk'
```

Comment: The file 'setters_getters.o' is pre-built and put into libsleep.a.  You need to have setters_getters.o built with '-mfloat-abi=hard'.  You can extract the file and run  `arm-none-eabi-readelf -A setters_getters.o` to see.  It is technically possible to make shims that could transfer the values.  But that doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: Hm I thought I was doing that. `setters_getters.c` is one of the files that will be compiled in my `for` loop using `-mfloat-abi=hard` into `setters_getters.o` (my 3rd line of args to `arm-none-eabi-gcc` set the FPU flags: `-mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard`

Comment: I just updated the question to add that detail, that all the object files have been compiled with hard floats.