# Problem cross-compiling trivial example with gcc when using hard float

Tags: gcc, arm, cross-compiling, cortex-m

When I try to compile a trivial example `test.c`

```c
int main () {
  return 0;
}
```

for a cortex m7 target with hard float ABI by using the following invocation

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m7 -mfpu=fpv5-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard --specs=nosys.specs test.c
```

I get this error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/6.3.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: error: /usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/6.3.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/crt0.o: Conflicting CPU architectures 13/1
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/6.3.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: failed to merge target specific data of file /usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/6.3.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/crt0.o
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/6.3.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: error: a.out uses VFP register arguments, /usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/6.3.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-atexit.o) does not
[snip]
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/6.3.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: failed to merge target specific data of file /usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/6.3.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libnosys.a(_exit.o)
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

So the issue is that gcc is linking to the wrong `libc.a`. If I use the argument `print-multi-directory`, it would appear that my version of `arm-none-eabi-gcc` should support this architecture:

```
$ arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m7 -mfpu=fpv5-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard --specs=nosys.specs --print-multi-directory
thumb/v7e-m/fpv5/hard
```

And I can list the different versions of `libc.a` that are provided by `arm-none-eabi-gcc`:

```
$ find /usr/lib/arm-none-eabi/ -name libc.a
/usr/lib/arm-none-eabi/newlib/armv7e-m/libc.a
/usr/lib/arm-none-eabi/newlib/armv7e-m/fpu/fpv5-sp-d16/libc.a
/usr/lib/arm-none-eabi/newlib/armv7e-m/fpu/libc.a
/usr/lib/arm-none-eabi/newlib/armv7e-m/fpu/fpv5-d16/libc.a
/usr/lib/arm-none-eabi/newlib/armv7e-m/softfp/fpv5-sp-d16/libc.a
/usr/lib/arm-none-eabi/newlib/armv7e-m/softfp/libc.a
/usr/lib/arm-none-eabi/newlib/armv7e-m/softfp/fpv5-d16/libc.a
/usr/lib/arm-none-eabi/newlib/libc.a
/usr/lib/arm-none-eabi/newlib/armv6-m/libc.a
/usr/lib/arm-none-eabi/newlib/fpu/libc.a
/usr/lib/arm-none-eabi/newlib/thumb/libc.a
/usr/lib/arm-none-eabi/newlib/armv7-m/libc.a
```

So it looks like there is a version of `libc.a` compiled for my desired architecture, but gcc isn't linking against it. How can I get gcc to link against the correct version of `libc.a`?

I'm using arm-none-eabi-gcc version 6.3.1 provided by the `gcc-arm-none-eabi` package for Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ARM compilation error, VFP registered used by executable, not object file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9753749/arm-compilation-error-vfp-registered-used-by-executable-not-object-file)

Comment: nosys is configured with soft float abi. You need to recompile newlib with hard float abi for your target cpu. Or recompile without `-specs=nosys.specs`

Comment: This problem persists without `-specs=nosys.specs`.

Comment: And based on the existence of `/usr/lib/arm-none-eabi/newlib/armv7e-m/fpu/fpv5-d16/libc.a`, it seems that there is a version of newlib compiled for hard float abi. I'm just confused why gcc is trying to link against the soft float version.

Comment: hm, good point, but he links with different file `/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/6.3.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a`. [gcc 7.3 on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/le1Why) just compiles... Maybe try something along `-nostdlib` and pass the proper libc.a along the command line? Looks like a related gcc bug I found, see https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-os/issues/7852

Comment: Don't use `-mcpu=cortex-m7`, use `-march=armv7e-m` to pick the right libraries.  This is similar to the other question, but it is not a duplicate in my opinion.  I imagine the multi-lib matching has improved over time to explain godbolt's success.

Comment: Related:  [Difference between hard and soft float (for ARM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321468/whats-the-difference-between-hard-and-soft-floating-point-numbers); also not a duplicate but very similar.  There are lots of different root causes of this error.

Comment: There is nothing "trivial" whatsoever with a C library, newlib or other they are massive and painful.

Comment: when you build newlib what command line does it use for the libraries and what happened when you tried that?  newlib is not part of the gnu toolchain you want a specific library you adjust your environment and/or paths and/or command line to point at it.  if it is a case of none of them work then try using the command line used when they build at least one of them.

Comment: I think the issue I was experiencing is documented here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/newlib/+bug/1767223 (linked from @kamil's comment). The solution was to download a newer version of gcc.